# Use javascript to show active state on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a persistent yellow menu here: http://jsfiddle.net/KCb5z/11/

As you can see it remains on the page. What I want to achieve is putting the active stage on the menu items once the user has scrolled to that section (i.e the yellow menu is either just on top of inside that current section)

It seems like there are a lot of different ways of attempting this but I really don't know how to start. Bootstrap does it here (when you scrolldown) http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ with something called scrollspy, but the code for that seems so large for something so simple:

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

Comment: This is not really a simple task not only the menu highlight needs to be set according to the scroll position, but also related to the anchor. And the other way round you also want to click on the menu to jump to the desired position. This jQuery plugin does what you want: http://trevordavis.net/blog/jquery-one-page-navigation-plugin/

Comment: If it were me in your position. I would start off with this: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/scrollspy.js, and remove any parts I didn't care for. Such as the data-api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go

```
 $(function () {

var $select = $('#select');
var $window = $(window);
var isFixed = false;
var init = $select.length ? $select.offset().top : 0;

$window.scroll(function () {
    var currentScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    if (currentScrollTop > init && isFixed === false) {
        isFixed = true;
        $select.css({
            top: 0,
            position: 'fixed'
        });
        $('body').css('padding-top', $select.height());
    } else if (currentScrollTop <= init && isFixed === true) {
        isFixed = false;
        $select.css('position', 'relative');

        $('body').css('padding-top', 0);
    }
    //active state in menu
    $('.section').each(function(){
        var eleDistance = $(this).offset().top;
        if (currentScrollTop >= eleDistance) {
            var makeActive = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#select a').removeClass('active');
            $('#select a.' + makeActive).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});

$(".nav").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var divId = $(this).attr('href');
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(divId).offset().top - $select.height()
    }, 500);
});



 });
```

[check the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AgBbK/)